# $\frac{|a|}{|b-c|} + \frac{|b|}{|c-a|} + \frac{|c|}{|b-a|} \geq 2$

Tags: inequality

If $a, b, c$ are distinct real numbers then you demonstrate that:

$$ S=\frac{|a|}{|b-c|} + \frac{|b|}{|c-a|} + \frac{|c|}{|b-a|} \geq 2.$$

Using inequality $ |x-y|\leq |x|+|y|$ we showed that  $  S >\frac{3}{2}.$

For $b = 2a, c = 3a, S=5,$ that is, the sum has values greater than 2, but I have not been able to prove this.

Comment: Put everyting on one side, multiply everything by $|b-c||c-a||b-a|, and go from there.

Comment: This question is lacking key context: what is the source of the problem, and what is its motivation?

Comment: @Carl Mummert: I do not see the point of your observation. Closing the topic raises many questions. Is this the first problem formulated on this group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\frac{a}{b-c}=x$, $\frac{b}{c-a}=y$ and $\frac{c}{a-b}=z$.

Thus, $$xy+xz+yz=\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{(b-c)(c-a)}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}ab(a-b)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}=\frac{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}=-1.$$
Id est,
$$\sum_{cyc}\left|\frac{a}{b-c}\right|=\sqrt{\left(|x|+|y|+|z|\right)^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2+2\sum\limits_{cyc}|xy|}=$$
$$=\sqrt{(x+y+z)^2+2+2\sum\limits_{cyc}|xy|}\geq\sqrt{2+2}=2.$$

Comment: +1, nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

Without loss of generality we can assume that $b$ and $c$ have the same sign. Then $|b|=|b-c|+|c|$. Also, $|c-a|\le |c|+|a|$ and $|a-b| \le |a|+|b-c|+|c|$. Therefore
$$
\frac{|a|}{|b-c|}+\frac{|b|}{|c-a|}+\frac{|c|}{|a-b|} \ge \frac{|a|}{|b-c|} + \frac{|b-c|+|c|}{|c|+|a|} + \frac{|c|}{|a|+|b-c|+|c|} = (*).$$

Denote $x=|a|$, $y=|b-c|$, $z=|c|$. Then, by Schwarz and by $x^2+y^2 \ge 2xy$, we get
\begin{align*}
(*) & = \frac{x}{y}+\frac{y+z}{z+x}+\frac{z}{x+y+z} \\
&\ge \frac{(x+(y+z)+z)^2}{xy+(y+z)(z+x)+z(x+y+z)} \\
&= \frac{x^2+y^2+4z^2+2xy+4yz+4zx}{2z^2+2xy+2yz+2zx} \\
&\ge \frac{2xy+4z^2+2xy+4yz+4zx}{2z^2+2xy+2yz+2zx} \\
&=2.\end{align*}

Comment: +1, nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $|x-y|\leq |x|+|y|$ implies that:
$$\frac{|z|}{|x-y|} \geq \frac{|z|}{|x|+|y|}.$$
Then:

$$S \geq \frac{|a|}{|b|+|c|} + \frac{|b|}{|a|+|c|} + \frac{|c|}{|a|+|b|} = \\
=\frac{A}{B+C} + \frac{B}{A+C} + \frac{C}{A+B},$$
 where I set $A = |a|, B = |b|$ and $C= |c|$ for the sake of simplicity.

Multiplying and dividing numerators and denominators by $(B+C)(A+C)(A+B)$, we get that:

$$S \geq \frac{A^3+A^2B + A^2 C + AB^2 + 3ABC + AC^2 + B^3 + B^2C + BC^2 + C^3 }{(B+C)(A+C)(A+B)}.$$

Notice that the denominator can be expanded as follows:

$$D = (B+C)(A+C)(A+B) = A^2B + A^2C + AB^2 + 2ABC + AC^2 + B^2C + BC^2.$$

Therefore, the numerator can be rewritten as:

$$ N= D + A^3 +B^3 + C^3 + ABC.$$

In other words:

$$S \geq \frac{D + A^3 +B^3 + C^3 + ABC}{D} > \frac{D}{D} = 1.$$

Comment: How does this prove that $S \ge 2$?

Comment: @timon92 It doesn't. This is my attempt. If I can find a better lower bound, then I will post it.

Comment: Fair enough. Also, using the so-called Nesbitt inequality one can get better bound: $S\ge \frac{|a|}{|b|+|c|}+\frac{|b|}{|c|+|a|}+\frac{|c|}{|a|+|b|} \ge \frac 32.$

Answer (score 0):

I tried to give a simple proof by reducing to simpler and simpler cases, all the time doing "nothing", and the final rephrasing is simple, too.

- First of all, let us note that the (LHS of the) given inequality is invariated by permutations of the letters / variables $a,b,c$. So we may and do assume $a\le b\le c$.
- Let $s,t>0$ be then such that $b=a+s$, $c=b+t=a+s+t$.
- Replacing the initial $a,b,c$ with $-c,-b,-a$, we may and do assume $b\ge 0$.
- The given inequality can now be rewritten equivalently:
  $$
  S=
  \frac{|a|}t +
  \frac{|a+s|}{s+t} +
  \frac{|a+s+t|}s
  \ge 2 \ .
  $$
- If $a$ is $\ge0$, then all three numbers $a,b,c$ are $\ge 0$, and we can write
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  S 
  &= \frac{|a|}t +
  \frac{|a+s|}{s+t} +
  \frac{|a+s+t|}s
  \\
  &\ge
  \frac{0}t +
  \frac{s}{s+t} +
  \frac{s+t}s
  %\ge 2\sqrt{
  %\frac{s}{s+t} \cdot
  %\frac{s+t}s}
  \ge2\ ,\qquad(a\ge 0)
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  and the last $\ge$ (AM-GM) is moreover $>0$ (because $t\ne 0$). The case with $a < b < c=a+s+t\le 0$ is similar.
- So the single interesting case is the one with $a<0\le b<c$ . We rewrite the inequality in the form:
  $$
  \frac{|b-s|}t+\frac b{s+t}+\frac{b+t}s\ge 2\ .
  $$
  Here, $b$ is allowed to vary between $0$ and $s$, and the first modulus is $|a|=-a=-(b-s)=s-b$, so we have to show:
  $$
  \frac{s-b}t+\frac b{s+t}+\frac{b+t}s\ge 2\ .
  $$
  But this is a linear (ergo convex) function in $b$, so the inequality has to be tested only for the possible extremities, $b=0$ and $b=s$. For $b=0$ we obtain $\frac st+\frac ts\ge 2$, true, with equality for $s=t$. For $b=s$ we get $\frac s{s+t}+\frac {s+t}s\ge 2$, an inequality of the same shape, but we cannot get equality. (For intermediate values of $b$ we get intermediate values of the expression.)